# TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [2] of <class 'int'>

Tags: python, pandas

I've been learning how to perform PCA in Python, and starting with the tutorial that uses the iris dataset (containing a limited number of features). In this code, it assigned the features to x by specifically naming them like this:

```
features = ['sepal length', 'sepal width', 'petal length', 'petal width'] 
x = df.loc[:, features].values
```

I'm now working with my own dataset that has about 270 features, so obviously I can't individually name the features. I've tried assigning the features to x with the following (without assigning the individual features to a variable first):

```
x = df.loc[:, 2:].values
```

But I get the error message:

> TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [2] of <class 'int'>

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I edited your question so it focuses on one question only. your error was about pandas. feel free to ask another question concerning the PCA part

Answer (score 2):

You're getting this error because the `loc` takes column names, not integers. For accessing the column at index 2, use `iloc`:

```
x = df.iloc[:, 2:].values
```

Comment: Ah, rookie mistake. Thanks very much, that sorted it!